# Appending an attribute to a Laravel 7.9.2 model?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Unit_Live extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'live_data_units';

    public function getUnitNameAttribute()
    {
        return "{$this->unitName}";
    }

    protected $appends = ['unit_name'];

}
```

Output:

[image: Attribute Issue]

If I change the `$appends` array, I can see `default`:

```
protected $appends = ['unit_name' => 'default'];
```

[image]

The expected output should be `unit_a`. `unitName` is a column in my table, value is shown under `#attributes` in image 1.

Docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: maybe Laravel is getting confused about the case, can you try another name, maybe `other_unit_name`, `getOtherUnitNameAttribute` ?

Comment: `getOtherUnitNameAttribute()` and `protected $appends = ['other_unit_name'];`  did not work. Good idea though.

Comment: maybe try `return $this->unitName;`

Comment: I tried a very variations of that. I also tried `return "hello";` to no avail.

Comment: do you have `protected $hidden = ['cpu']` that is hidding the field maybe?

Comment: No, I have nothing hidden.

Comment: Is this the same for all your model? It's quite strange - maybe not supported in your Laravel version

Comment: I tried it on a couple of other models without luck as well. Its well-documented on my version of Laravel which makes this a headscratcher.

Comment: I wondered if `protected $table` could have something to do with it, so I created a new model named `Unit` for the table `units` and imported data to it. Still no luck and this is as minified as I think I could go.

Comment: It's really odd.. it never failed to work for me - everything looks as per the book. If you really need to debug, try to create a quick new Laravel app and play with the User model see if it works